# Web audio volume change on two sliders

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have asked this question previously but deleted it because it was the wrong code, i am currently working on a radio player and kinda new in Javascript, i need to add two volume sliders and when one goes up the other one also needs to go up with it. I tried checking and tried everything but nothing seems to help. What am i doing wrong?

This is my current code (give it some time to load the radio player)

```js
const audio = document.querySelector('#stream')
const playPauseButton = document.querySelector('[name="play-pause"]')
const playPauseButtonIcon = playPauseButton.querySelector('i.fas')
const volumeControl = document.querySelector('[name="volume"]')
const currentlyPlaying = document.querySelector('.currently-playing-title')


let isPlaying = false
let fetchInterval = null
let currentVolume = 0.8

audio.volume = currentVolume

const fetchCurrentlyPlaying = () => fetch('...')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => currentlyPlaying.innerText = data.currentSong)


volumeControl.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const volume = parseFloat(volumeControl.value)

    audio.volume = currentVolume = volume
    currentVolume = volume

})


playPauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
        audio.pause()

        playPauseButtonIcon.classList.remove('fa-pause')
        playPauseButtonIcon.classList.add('fa-play')

        clearInterval(fetchInterval)
        currentlyPlaying.innerText = 'Er wordt geen nummer gedraaid'
    } else {
        audio.play()

        playPauseButtonIcon.classList.remove('fa-play')
        playPauseButtonIcon.classList.add('fa-pause')

        fetchCurrentlyPlaying()
        fetchInterval = setInterval(fetchCurrentlyPlaying, 3000)
    }

    isPlaying = !isPlaying
})
```

```css
.radio-player {
    margin: 30px;
}
.button {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-color: #F59E0B;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.play-pause-button {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 24px;
}
.mute-button {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.player-controls {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.currently-playing {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.volume-controls {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.currently-playing-label {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.currently-playing-title {
    font-size: 22px;
}

.volume {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden; /* This will help with styling the thumb */
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;

    cursor: ew-resize;
    background: #F59E0B;
    box-shadow: -400px 0 0 390px #FDE68A;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    /* same as above */
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
    /* same as above */
}
input[type="range"]:focus {
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px -4px #F59E0B;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="radio-player">
    <audio src="https://live.hostingbudget.nl:1045/stream" class="visually-hidden" id="stream">
        <!-- More stuff here -->
    </audio>
</div>
<div class="player-controls">
    <button name="play-pause" class="button play-pause-button" aria-label="Play/pause">
        <i class="fas fa-play" aria-hidden></i>
    </button>

    <div class="volume-and-title">
        <div class="currently-playing" aria-label="Currently playing">
            <span class="currently-playing-label">Now playing on Some Radio Station</span>
            <span class="currently-playing-title">Listen to Some Radio Station</span>
        </div>

        <div class="volume-controls">
            <input type="range" name="volume" class="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="0.2" aria-label="Volume">
            <input type="range" name="volume2" class="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="0.2" aria-label="Volume">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/radioaudio.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Source code](https://dev.to/thormeier/let-s-build-a-web-radio-player-from-scratch-2poo)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is add the event listener to the parent div. Then in the event listener, get the value of the slider and assign it to both sliders:

```js
const audio = document.querySelector('#stream')
const playPauseButton = document.querySelector('[name="play-pause"]')
const playPauseButtonIcon = playPauseButton.querySelector('i.fas')
// *** Use the parent div
const volumeControl = document.querySelector('[class="volume-controls"]');
const currentlyPlaying = document.querySelector('.currently-playing-title')


let isPlaying = false
let fetchInterval = null
let currentVolume = 0.8

audio.volume = currentVolume

const fetchCurrentlyPlaying = () => fetch('...')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => currentlyPlaying.innerText = data.currentSong)


volumeControl.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    // Get the value from whichever slider caused the event
    const volume = parseFloat(e.srcElement.value);

    // Assign the value to all sliders
    document.querySelectorAll('[type="range"]').forEach((v) => v.value = volume);

    audio.volume = currentVolume = volume
    currentVolume = volume

})


playPauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
        audio.pause()

        playPauseButtonIcon.classList.remove('fa-pause')
        playPauseButtonIcon.classList.add('fa-play')

        clearInterval(fetchInterval)
        currentlyPlaying.innerText = 'Er wordt geen nummer gedraaid'
    } else {
        audio.play()

        playPauseButtonIcon.classList.remove('fa-play')
        playPauseButtonIcon.classList.add('fa-pause')

        fetchCurrentlyPlaying()
        fetchInterval = setInterval(fetchCurrentlyPlaying, 3000)
    }

    isPlaying = !isPlaying
})
```

```css
.radio-player {
    margin: 30px;
}
.button {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-color: #F59E0B;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.play-pause-button {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 24px;
}
.mute-button {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.player-controls {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.currently-playing {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.volume-controls {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.currently-playing-label {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.currently-playing-title {
    font-size: 22px;
}

.volume {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden; /* This will help with styling the thumb */
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;

    cursor: ew-resize;
    background: #F59E0B;
    box-shadow: -400px 0 0 390px #FDE68A;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    /* same as above */
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
    /* same as above */
}
input[type="range"]:focus {
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px -4px #F59E0B;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-player">
    <audio src="https://live.hostingbudget.nl:1045/stream" class="visually-hidden" id="stream">
        <!-- More stuff here -->
    </audio>
</div>
<div class="player-controls">
    <button name="play-pause" class="button play-pause-button" aria-label="Play/pause">
        <i class="fas fa-play" aria-hidden></i>
    </button>

    <div class="volume-and-title">
        <div class="currently-playing" aria-label="Currently playing">
            <span class="currently-playing-label">You are listening to radio</span>
            <span class="currently-playing-title">Currently playing:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="volume-controls">
            <input type="range" name="volume" class="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="0.2" aria-label="Volume">
            <input type="range" name="volume2" class="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="0.2" aria-label="Volume">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```